# changing the size of array as required: C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-arrays

This program is to find all prime numbers and store them in an array. I don't want to take unnecessary memory by defining a fixed array before getting the exact number of prime numbers in a specific range. I also want to make this code to be able to run in C89 so, variable sized array is out of question here.
This is my code with 2 methods I found for this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct prime{
    int *arr;
    int count;
};
int prmchk();
struct prime method1();
struct prime method2();
int main()
{
    int min,max;
    int i,j;
    struct prime p[2];
    printf("Enter limits of range..\n");
    printf("min: ");
    scanf("%d",&min);
    printf("max: ");
    scanf("%d",&max);

    p[0] = method1(min,max);
    p[1] = method2(min,max);

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)                 //to test the results by printing them
    {                                      //has nothing to do with the problem
        printf("result of method %d: ",i+1);
        for(j = 0; j < p[i].count; j++)
            printf("%d ",p[i].arr[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
struct prime method1(int min, int max)        //function starts
{
    struct prime pf;
    int i;
    int temparr[10000];         //No 2 consecutive no.s can be prime numbers simulteneously
    int pcount = 0;
    for(i = min; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if(prmchk(i) == 1)
        temparr[pcount++] = i;       //
    }

    pf.arr = (int*) malloc(pcount * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < pcount; i++)
    {
        pf.arr[i] = temparr[i];
    }
    pf.count = pcount;
    return pf;
}
struct prime method2(int min, int max)
{
    struct prime pf;
    pf.arr = (int*) malloc(0);
    int i;
    int pcount = 0;
    for(i = min; i < max; i++)
    {
        if(prmchk(i) == 1)
        {
            pf.arr = (int*) realloc(pf.arr,++pcount*sizeof(int));
            pf.arr[pcount-1] = i;
        }
    }
        pf.count = pcount;
        return pf;
}
int prmchk(int num)
{
    int i;

    if(num == 1)
    return 0;
    if(num == 2)
    return 1;
    for(i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if(num%i == 0)
        return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

My questions are

1. Since I'm new to competitive programming I don't know which method will consume less memory and which one will consume less time. I want to know which method is better than the other.
   If possible feel free to add a new method if you can think of any.
2. Can we use malloc(0) as used here
3. How the readability of this particular code could be improved more. I'm read some articles about it. But unable to get any proper understanding.

Comment: "I don't want to take unnecessary memory" What do you think this does? `int temparr[10000];`

Comment: To find primes quickly, you might want to use the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @Lundin first of all that is not the method I think is correct That's why I asked to tell me which one is the best among them.
 Also when the function ends won't the allocated memory will be gone too.
I mean is that a bad thing?

Comment: There is no reason to `malloc(0)`, since `realloc` will act like `malloc` when fed null as the first argument. Regarding an initial population of element count, when asking the question "how many primes are at or below x?" a value of `x/(ln x - 1)` is a good approximation. It will generally be *slightly* lowballed, so a fractional increase is likely (i.e. you'll probably have at least one realloc, but you can limit that too with a generous enough over-alloc initially.

Comment: You can over-allocate (eg: by doubling the size each time you run out of space), and downsize the memory at the end using realloc. It's correct, easy, and less prone to accidental quadratic behavior. Although the way you're finding the primes is already quadratic, so your code already has bad performance. Sieve of Erastothenes (as someone else suggested) is not the absolute best way of finding primes, but it's a huge improvement over what you're doing.

Comment: Note that you don't need to search up to N-1; up to and including `ceil(sqrt(N))` is sufficient. If N is composite, then one factor is not larger than √N and the other
is not smaller than √N). After you've checked for 'divisible by 2', you could check only the odd numbers. If you check for 'divisible by 3' outside the loop, then all bigger primes have the form 6K±1 for an integer K starting at K equal to 1.
Limiting the search range gives a radical speedup even when N is just in
the thousands, let alone much bigger. Using 'odds only' does 1/2 the work; using 6K±1 does 1/3.

Comment: If the range to be searched is big enough (the maximum value is large
enough), building a Sieve of Eratosthenes (or even more advanced
techniques — such as Sieve of Atkin) for the primes up to the square
root of the maximum and then testing only the 'known to be prime'
possible factors can be beneficial.

Eventually, deterministic evaluation of 'is it a prime' becomes too slow
and you resort to probabilistic prime detection such as the Miller-Rabin
test.

See Wikipedia on [Primality
test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).